# Bash aliases not recognized after uninstalling oh my zsh

Tags: bash, oh-my-zsh

After I attempted to uninstall oh-my-zsh, I am getting the error

> /Users/Thomas/.zshrc:source:56: no such file or directory: /Users/Thomas/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh

[This issue](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/35) indicates that the original shell needs to be reverted back to, however the provided command

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

is not working. I've restarted my iTerm as well. And my aliases still don't work, as well as exported variables such as `$JAVA_HOME` return empty, even though they are properly set using my former *.bash_profile*.  Also rather than ending with a `~` my terminal prompt ends with a `%`

```
Thomas%
```

How can I revert?

One detail, when I attempted the uninstall via `uninstall_oh_my_zsh` I mistyped my password. Rather than prompting me again, it looked as though it went ahead and completed the uninstall, but maybe some component of it didn't complete properly.

Comment: What is the output when you type `alias`?

Comment: @EliSadoff `run-help=man
which-command=whence`

Comment: Also, do you have a `.bashrc` or just `.bash_profile`?

Comment: I have a `.bash_profile`. I've never used a `.bashrc` and don't see it in the `~/` directory @EliSadoff

Comment: What do you mean when you say `chsh -s /bin/bash` isn't working? What happens exactly?

Comment: I believe, and I could be wrong, that aliases classically go in `.bashrc` because its read in every shell whereas `.bash_profile` is only read in login shells.

Comment: @jjst the comment from the git issue indicates that that command will revert my shell back to the original non-zsh shell. however, that doesn't seem to be the case, because my aliases declared in bash_profile don't work

Comment: @EliSadoff does that go for exported variables as well. Like `echo $JAVA_HOME` => empty line.

Comment: What happens when you type `bash` in your terminal (just to make sure that you're running in bash)? Do your aliases work then?

Comment: `bash-3.2$ is displayed as a prompt. aliases still don't work @jjst

Comment: @jjst I'm thinking this thing still things it's on zsh. typing in a command like `asdf` returns `zsh: command not found: asdf`. However `uninstall_oh_my_zsh` also doesn't work, with the same result

Comment: Uninstalling `oh-my-zsh` is not the same as uninstalling `zsh`. You just have to remove the line attempting to source `/Users/Thomas/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh` from your `.zshrc` file. `bash` shouldn't have anything to do with your problem.

Comment: @chepner In fact the command listed [here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/1675) worked for me to convert back to bash. In order to use ohmyzsh with the aliases and exports i'm used to using from normal `.bash_profile`, should those all be added to `.zshrc`

Comment: `oh-my-zsh` is not a shell; it's a canned configuration for `zsh`. If you have aliases in `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` that you want to use with `zsh`, then yes, they need to be added to `.zshrc`.

Comment: In order for `chsh -s /bin/bash` to take effect, you have to actually re-login. Also, ensure that `iTerm` is not explicitly set to run `zsh` as shell.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Brew installed.

Enter `brew remove zsh` into the terminal then reset your terminal, it should reconfigure back to your original shell.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of error, you need to check if you set the default bash to zsh in .bashrc file. So, if there is any, just comment them out. 
Example for mine.

```
#Launch Zsh
if [ -t 1 ]; then
exec zsh
fi
```

So, you just need to comment that out.

```
#Launch Zsh
#if [ -t 1 ]; then
#exec zsh
#fi
```